# c# linq join on two columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How would you write the following sql statement using linq?

```
select * from contacts 
inner join messages on contacts.contactnumber = messages.[to] or contacts.contactnumber = messages.[from]
```

I need to join on 2 columns but the value can be matching on either column. It would never match on both. I have found how to join on both columns but not "or".

The following example works only when both columns which is not what i am wanting here:

```
var contact = (from c in db.Contacts
                           join m in db.message on new { A= c.ContactNumber, B = c.ContactNumber}  equals  new {A = m.to , B = m.@from }
                           where m.id !=null
                           select(c));

            return contact ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using two `from`s instead:

```
var contact = (from c in db.Contacts
               from m in db.message
               where c.contactnumber == m.to ||
               c.contactnumber == m.from
               select c);
return contact ;
```